# How to use `rename` rename a list of files in Linux

Tags: rename, file-rename

I want to use `rename` to process a bundle of files like this:

```bash
GSM5901579_203007520013_R01C01_Grn.idat.gz -> 203007520013_R01C01_Grn.idat.gz
GSM5901579_203007520013_R01C01_Red.idat.gz -> 203007520013_R01C01_Red.idat.gz
GSM5901580_203007520013_R03C01_Grn.idat.gz -> 203007520013_R03C01_Grn.idat.gz
```

I would be grateful if you can give any suggestion!

Comment: Does [Batch renaming files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1140/266568) answer your question?

Comment: "_This answer don't works for me ... I'm wondering how to use wildcard character to represent the variantes_", that's somehow already mentioned within the linked answer.

Comment: @U880D THX! follow the linked answer, I use `zmv -w 'GSM590*_(203*.idat)' '$2' `solve my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1141), I use the following command solve my problem!

```bash
zmv -w 'GSM590*_(203*.idat)' '$2'
```